# What is the interest of Grothendieck ring in Model theory

Tags: model-theory, grothendieck-rings

I've hear of the notion of Grothendieck ring in model theory.
Could someone tell me what are their interest and what are the relevant questions about them ?
I'm sorry for this quite vague question.